# How to use a template class as a type parameter for the same template class

Tags: c++, templates, g++

I'm trying to instantiate a template class using an instantiation of the *same* template class as the type. Previous answers using an instantiation of a *different* template class suggest that this code should work:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <typeinfo>

template <class T> class pair {
private:
    T first;
    T second;
public:
    pair(T x, T y) {
        first = x;
        second = y;
    }

    void printit() {
        if (typeid(int) == typeid(T)) {
            printf("pair(%i,%i)\n", first, second);
        } else {
            printf("type not supported yet\n");
        }
    }
};
int main(int argc, char ** argv) {
    printf("simplertest\n");
    int one = 1;
    int two = 2;
    pair<int> pi(one,two);
    pair<pair<int> > pp(pi, pi); // should make pair whose members are pairs
}
```

but I get an error from g++

```
> g++ simplertest.cpp
simplertest.cpp: In instantiation of ‘pair<T>::pair(T, T) [with T = pair<int>]’:
simplertest.cpp:27:31:   required from here
simplertest.cpp:9:20: error: no matching function for call to ‘pair<int>::pair()’
     pair(T x, T y) {
                    ^
simplertest.cpp:9:5: note: candidate: pair<T>::pair(T, T) [with T = int]
     pair(T x, T y) {
     ^~~~
simplertest.cpp:9:5: note:   candidate expects 2 arguments, 0 provided
simplertest.cpp:4:26: note: candidate: constexpr pair<int>::pair(const pair<int>&)
 template <class T> class pair {
                          ^~~~
simplertest.cpp:4:26: note:   candidate expects 1 argument, 0 provided
simplertest.cpp:4:26: note: candidate: constexpr pair<int>::pair(pair<int>&&)
simplertest.cpp:4:26: note:   candidate expects 1 argument, 0 provided
simplertest.cpp:9:20: error: no matching function for call to ‘pair<int>::pair()’
     pair(T x, T y) {
                    ^
simplertest.cpp:9:5: note: candidate: pair<T>::pair(T, T) [with T = int]
     pair(T x, T y) {
     ^~~~
simplertest.cpp:9:5: note:   candidate expects 2 arguments, 0 provided
simplertest.cpp:4:26: note: candidate: constexpr pair<int>::pair(const pair<int>&)
 template <class T> class pair {
                          ^~~~
simplertest.cpp:4:26: note:   candidate expects 1 argument, 0 provided
simplertest.cpp:4:26: note: candidate: constexpr pair<int>::pair(pair<int>&&)
simplertest.cpp:4:26: note:   candidate expects 1 argument, 0 provided
> g++ --version
g++ (SUSE Linux) 7.5.0
Copyright (C) 2017 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO
warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 1):

The issue is that you are using *assignment* over *initialization* in your `pair` constructor.

```
pair(T x, T y) 
{ //here
    first = x;
    second = y;
}
```

By the time the opening bracket (marked with comment) is reached, all of the data members in class must be initialized.
`int` has default initializer, so there is no problem with `pair<int>` - `first` and `second` are default initialized and then overridden in your constructor body.
However, `pair` does not provide a default constructor. When you try `pair<pair<int>>` (so `T` is of type `pair<int>`) `first` and `second` cannot be initialized, thus the error.

The solution is to use [member initilization list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1711990/what-is-this-weird-colon-member-syntax-in-the-constructor):

```
pair(T x, T y) : first{x}, second{y}
{
}
```

Comment: "all of the data " not really "all" of them must be initialized

Comment: @largest_prime_is_463035818 Can you elaborate? Which data members can be not initialized before constructor body?

Comment: i refer to "all of the data members in class must be initialized". Could be more clear. Specifically there was no problem with assignment in the constructor in OPs `pair<int>` to the `int` member ( `int` has no default constructor too ;)

Comment: largest_prime_is_463035818, I think `int` *does* have a default constructor, whatever random value is in the memory cell allocated. Perhaps Yksisarvinen should have said "must be constructed" rather than "must be initialized", or maybe "all data members which are classes or contain classes". A class member which is a `struct`, for example, does not need to be initialized.